# ember and watchman "warning: lost connection to watchman reconnecting"

Tags: html, css, model-view-controller, ember.js, handlebars.js

i'm learning ember and i'm trying to follow the quick start guide they provide, as i can see ember uses watchman to watch files which i already installed, when i run "ember server" it works fine but when i generate a new route or a new component i get a warning saying " lost connection to watchman reconnecting... ", i tried reinstalling watchman again, but still have the same problem, my operating system is Ubuntu 16.04. I need a bit of help trying to fix this, because at the moment i'm just stopping the server and restarting it to make it work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which version of Ember Cli and Ember are you using now?

Comment: The version i'm using is 2.8.0